# Menu dropdown disapears behind slider

Tags: menus

First off I do not know where I am.  Never been here and may never even realize if someone has an answer for this.
I am using a theme called Spacious Pro.  I have drop downs in my menu.  When the site is viewed on an explorer browser the drop down menu tabs disapear behind the slider.  This does not happen on any other browser.
info@thompsonaire.com is how to contact me.

Comment: Soliciting email replies is not recommended. You get to ask a public question and you hopefully receive public replies, which also hopefully help future visitors with the same problem; and if you don't like those terms, perhaps this site is not for you.

Comment: Do you have to make the website explorer-friendly?
The majority of themes and plugins just doesn't support it anymore (many themes and bootstrap also uses css which explorer can't understand, and also WP starting from version 4.9 or 5 I'm not sure).
Also actual number of users stuck with that browser is very low, around 3-4%(though this may greatly vary based on region).
On xp machines you still can install the latest firefox or chrome, and win7 and 8 support the latest windows explorer which has support for newer features.
I wouldn't support anything under explorer 11, if it's possible.